# execute python package to download a pdf file

Tags: command-line, python

i am new in python. please dont bore. i have a python package to download pdf file from a specific site. i can not execute this package. Please help me someone to execute the package. thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by a python package? A script?

Comment: no. its a package with some script.

Comment: Install the package then..is it a `.deb` package?

Comment: No problem..lets [go here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25577/room-for-heemayl-and-md-jabed-ali)

Comment: i cannt chat there... i mail you. please check your mail.

Comment: whats the package you have downloaded ? from where ? what does it contain ?